# chain rule with scalars, vectors, and matrices

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

Consider two differentiable functions, 
$f : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}.$
In general, for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, what is the gradient $\nabla_x (f \circ g) (a)$ for some point $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

My answer is that 
$$
\nabla_x  (f \circ g)(a) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left\langle  \left[ \frac{df}{dY} \big|_{g(a)} \right]^\top, \frac{dg}{dx_1}\big|_a\right\rangle \\
\left\langle  \left[ \frac{df}{dY} \big|_{g(a)} \right]^\top, \frac{dg}{dx_2}\big|_a \right\rangle
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The dimensions work, but I am not convinced.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you mean by ${df\over dY}$, but I guess you have the right thing in mind. Note that writing ${\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$ instead of ${\mathbb R}^{n^2}$ has no "matricial" effect, it just means that the components of $g$ are not numbered from $1$ to $n^2$, but in $[n]\times [n]$ format.

I'd write the gradient of $h:=f\circ g$ as follows:
$$\nabla h(a)=\sum_{i,\>k}{\partial f\over \partial y_{ik}}\bigl(g(a)\bigr)\left[\matrix{ g_{ik.1}(a)\cr g_{ik.2}(a)\cr}\right]\ .$$

Comment: I think by $g_{ik.1}(a)$ you mean (in my notational convention above) $\frac{dg_{ik}}{dx_1}\big|_a$.  If this is so, than you have shown me that, if the inner product in my question is taken to be $\langle A,B\rangle = Trace(A^\top B)$, then out answers are almost the same -- I have an erroneous transpose in there for some reason.